# Nunjucks how to pass variables through extends

Tags: nunjucks

Not sure if this has been answered, but I can't find a clear conversation on this.  I have Nunjucks project with the following file :

`index04.html`

In that file I have the following logic

```js
{% extends "parts/layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
  {% include "forms/my-form04-content.htm" %}
{% endblock %}
```

I would really like to create a variable on this page that can I pass down into `parts/layout.html`. How do I set that up and access it within my layout.html page?

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer my own question directly, the end result is good enough for me.

#### Using the data attribute with [gulp-nunjucks-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nunjucks-render)

> With this approach, I can pass CSS class values through the given `data` attribute. Not only that, but it would be available for me to access within any point inside my project. Pretty nice!

```cpp
function genNunJucks(done) {
    return src(['src/views/*.html'],['src/views/pages/*.html'], ['src/views/parts/*.html'])
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: ['src/views/'], // String or Array
            ext: '.html',
            data: {
                form4HTMLClass: 'form4class form4class-alt',
                form5HTMLClass: 'form5class form5class-alt',
            },
            inheritExtension: false,
            envOptions: {
                watch: true
            },
            manageEnv: null,
            loaders: null
        }))
        .pipe(dest('public'))
        .pipe(msync.stream());
    done();
}
```

```cpp
  ...<div class="container-fluid p-0 {{form4HTMLClass}}">...
```